# How to set min date and max date for dxDateBox?

Tags: devextreme

How can I set minimum date and maximum date for a dxDateBox. I am using the Devextreme controls

```
<div id="divValidityDate" data-bind="dxDateBox: {}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
<div id="divValidityDate" data-bind="dxDateBox: { min: new Date(2010, 9, 10), max: new Date(2010, 11, 10) }"></div>
```